# How to align and stretch the children when flex-direction is column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center-align the children inside a flex container and they also stretch. In addition the children have a max-width. Why don't they stretch?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uanm1qjb/1/)

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    Hello world
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Hello universe
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply remove align-items: center; (it disable the stretch effect)

Comment: or add width:100% to the child item

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunterberg/wbrk82s6/12/) the result you're trying to achieve? If not then just do what Temani said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use max-width the box will keep the width of the text inside + paddings + margins.
If you want the children to have the same width you have to set

```
min-width && max-width
```

so the children will be fixed to 500px

solution 2:
give the "wrap" container these rules

```
width:500px; align-items: stretch;
```

the boxes will stretch by the dimension of their container.
Also if you want to center the container you can add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to "wrap" class.